# Unable to click on the logout link using selenium webdriver 3.0.1

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have written the below code to logout from the [http://www.quikr.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz89t.png) once logged in. But when I run the below code using the firefox browser the code runs without any issues but webdriver fails to click on the sign out link.

Could you please suggest on the same.

**Note:** The same code works just fine with the chrome browser.

**I'm Using:**

> **Firefox Version:** 49.0.1 **Chrome Version:** 54.0.2840.59 m **Selenium
>   Version:** 3.0.1 **OS:** Win10 64 bit **Java:** 1.8

```
public static void doLogout(){          
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);          
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='responsiveHeader']/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a/i"))).click();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Sign Out"))).click();
}
```

[image]

Comment: try with the latest gecko driver (v.0.11.1 as of now) for firefox https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases. another alternative is, try with action chains - double click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sign Out link is only visible after scrolling in the drop down.

```
First Rule: For clicking on element - that element should be visible on screen.
Second Rule: To make it visible you need to scroll to that element.
```

For that after opening user drop down write below code.

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='responsiveHeader']/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/ul/li[9]/a")); // Sign Out element 
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele); // scrolling upto "Sign Out" element.
// Quikr has some problem of scrolling in website - so, we have to again scroll to top.
js.executeScript("scroll(0, 0);");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign Out")).click();
```

This code is working fine. I have tested properly. If you like it and it works well for you then accept the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Thanks for the solution Yojna. But I have a question the code works fine without scrolling to the element explicitly in chrome. How is that possible?

Comment: The javascript execution method in chrome driver and firefox is different. I can see that in chrome driver without scrolling in dropdown signOut is visible. So, no need to scroll in chrome driver. Your code should be perfect to run on all the browsers.